# What is Motoko Kusanagi's nationality and ethnicity?

Tags: anime, ghost-in-the-shell, manga

Ignoring the transhuman aspect of Major's prosthesis, was Motoko Kusanagi ever intended, in either the manga or anime, to be non-Japanese?

I'm asking due to the current #IAmMajor campaign being subverted due to the supposed whitewashing in the new film by casting Scarlett Johansson for the part.

Just to make things abundantly clear, I'm interested in her *birth* nationality and ethnicity, nothing post-prosthesis, even though that is an interesting dicussion.

Comment: I won't speak for the answer, but the creator of the series has praised the casting for the movie. Also, the fact that her name is a pseudonym and her gender may not even be the same as her birth gender... complicates things. In SAC, this was even a plot point.

Comment: @Terriblefan I've heard that the creator had praised / approved of the casting, though I've not seen evidence (worth a question?). You make good points about the pseudonym and birth gender, but I'm ignoring that under the transhuman part

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=35332784#35332784

Comment: Director, my bad. I don't know regarding the creator.

Comment: Producer has praised the casting (the rights holder, with a nice monetary interest), but the actual writer/creator has been  silent on the matter.

Comment: Very extensively discussed here on Quora; https://www.quora.com/Is-Major-Motoko-Kusanagi-from-Ghost-in-the-Shell-Caucasian

Comment: I like this from the Quora discussion: While Motoko Kusanagi [...] is legally speaking a human being with human rights, her Shell is a machine, and machines don’t have a race, do they? Does Motoko still have a race? Is she aracial? Is she a new race, as a “cyborg” or “post-human”?

Comment: @ench In the animated movie she has light eyes, light skin, a protruding chin, a sharp nose, and creases above her eyelids. Her hair looks Asian, but that's about it. Unless it was solely the producer's decision on how her animated character should look, I would say the producer and director both likely agreed with the live action casting.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the Ghost In The Shell: Stand Alone Complex - 2nd Gig (the second season of tv series), her original 6 year old body suffered a severe trauma in a plane crash, and she had to be cyberized to continue living. Almost nobody else survived that crash. Her parents were flying with her, and they died.

So… we can assume they were Japanese? Or they could have been on an international flight? After all, the cyberization happened in Japan, so she could have just gotten a standard Japanese model body (as slightly suggested in a scene in the original 1995 movie, where she sees "herself" or a lookalike in a window).

I don't think there's any canon information that strongly suggests one way or another.